# ifstream ignoring spaces and new lines - why?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

So I am writing a simple program just trying to understand why it is ignoring spaces (it treats them as new lines) and why it does not account for new lines.

Language: *C++*

Platform: *Kubuntu 13.04*

Compiler: *g++*

Code:

```
 unsigned int lines;
 string line_content;
 ifstream r_tftpd_hpa("/etc/default/tftpd-hpa"); // open file

    // test for errors
if ( r_tftpd_hpa.fail() ) {
    cerr << "Error opening file: \"/etc/default/tftpd-hpa\"" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

    // loop through file until end
while ( !r_tftpd_hpa.eof() ) {
    r_tftpd_hpa >> line_content;
    lines++;

                          // I also tried with \n
    if ( line_content[0] == ' ' ) { // my failed attempt at catching spaces
        cout << endl << "Found empty line: " << lines << endl;
    }

    cout << "Line: " << lines << " content: " << line_content << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
 Line: 1 content: #
 Line: 2 content: /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
 Line: 3 content: TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
 Line: 4 content: TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
 Line: 5 content: TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
 Line: 6 content: TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
 Line: 7 content: TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

The file itself:

```
 # /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

 TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
 TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
 TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
 TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

This file consists of 6 lines, however it seems to think it is 7. It counts the space after `#` in line 1 as a new line and ignores the space at line two in the original file. Also it prints line `6 and 7` as if there were two of the same line, there is not.

Any idea what is going on here? How do we deal with spaces and newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator >>` eats any whitespaces (newline, tab, space). If you need to count the number of lines, you can use the [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) function.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned lines = 0;
  string line_content;

  ifstream r_tftpd_hpa ("tftpd-hpa");
  assert(r_tftpd_hpa);

  while ( getline(r_tftpd_hpa, line_content) ) {
    lines++;

    if ( line_content[0] == ' ' ) { // my failed attempt at catching spaces
      cout << endl << "Found empty line: " << lines << endl;
    }

    cout << "Line: " << lines << " content: " << line_content << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

gives me:

```
Line: 1 content: # /etc/default/tftpd-hpa
Line: 2 content: 
Line: 3 content: TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
Line: 4 content: TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
Line: 5 content: TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
Line: 6 content: TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

Comment: The `noskipws` part made it go really far, Line: 1159352 content: 
Line: 1159353 content:  and so on. The `getline` part worked partly, however it still skipped the first line beggining with **#**.

Comment: @dusz I tried the code and it worked fine. See my updated post with the complete program.

Comment: Thank you, the line that did the trick was `assert()`, will have to do some more reading, setting as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because using `>>` to extract into a `std::string` will just read characters until it hits whitespace. That is, it reads a "word", rather than a line as you are expecting it to.

If you want to read a line delimited by `\n`, use `std::getline`:

```
std::getline(r_tftpd_hpa, line_content);
```

However, you'll have another problem to do with your use of `eof` as the condition of your `while` loop. Just because you haven't hit the end of file yet, it doesn't meant the next line extraction will succeed. This typically happens at the end of a file where there is a `\n` before the end of the file. The `\n` will be extracted and the EOF bit won't be set, so the loop will continue and attempt to extract another line. This results in the last line of your file appearing to be read twice. To get around this, move your `std::getline` into the condition of your `while` loop:

```
while (std::getline(r_tftpd_hpa, line_content))
```

Comment: That is indeed better, however now it seems to be ignoring the fist line _#_, why is that?